# Logstash s3 input plugin not processing gz files giving Not in GZIP format error

Tags: logstash

I am getting the following error when pulling gz log files from s3 using logstash.

```
[2019-04-19T20:40:31,267][ERROR][logstash.inputs.s3       ] Failed to read the file. Skip processing. 
{:filename=>"C:/Users/mgurupr1/home/logstash/testdata.gz", :exception=>"Not in GZIP format"}
```

My configuration file is as follows:

```
input {
s3 {
      access_key_id => "access key"
      bucket => "bucketname"
      secret_access_key => "secret"
      endpoint => "endpoint"
     prefix => "prefix"
      add_field => { source => gzfiles }
additional_settings => {
      "force_path_style" => true
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help?

Comment: can you add the logstash config file you are using?

Comment: I have updated the configuration file. Can some one please help?

Comment: @GuruprasathM Did you manage to solve it?
I'm facing the same issue, I'm getting the following error while trying to read GZ from S3

Failed to read file, processing skipped {:exception=>Java::JavaUtilZip::ZipException, :message=>"Not in GZIP format"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the gzip codec?

```
        s3 {
      access_key_id => "access key"
      bucket => "bucketname"
      secret_access_key => "secret"
      endpoint => "endpoint"
     prefix => "prefix"
      add_field => { source => gzfiles }
additional_settings => {
      "force_path_style" => true
    }
      codec => gzip_lines
    }
}
```